# How to overwrite `show scroll bars` of chrome in React project?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome

The default value of `Show scroll bars` is `Automatically base on mouse or trackpad`. I need to set it to `Always` in system preference settings if I want to show the scroll bar always. But I have many customers, I can't have them all set manually. I wonder how to set it with code in React project?

I want to display the scroll bar when I open the website, not need to set manually.[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Mac to try it out, but I would recommend this in CSS :

```
body {
  overflow: scroll;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: xxx; //your value
   height: xxx; // your value
}
```

What I am sure, is that you can't change the OS settings of your users